# Как разместить 2 проекта Laravel на одном домене

Tags: laravel

Есть 1 домен и 2 проекта на Laravel
Нужно в зависимости от поддомена открывать один из проектов
Список поддоменов хранится в БД

Думал сделать 3 папки

1) Папка домена, в ней находится фаил index.php в котором находится проверка на адрес сайта и в зависимости от результата он подключает(include, require) public/index.php из нужной папки
2) Папка с 1 проектом
3) Папка со 2 проектом

Но затея провалилась, как я понял при подключении файла public/index.php laravel думает, что она находится в папке домена и не видит файлы(т.к в папке с доменом только 1 фаил index.php)

Как разместить 2 проекта Laravel на одном домене?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так делится не ларавелем, а вэб сервером (apache или nginx)
Просто для поддомена нужно сделать отдельный конфиг и направить в любую нужную папку на серваке, а там уже лара подхватит